# Chrome application loading images from local source

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I am creating a web application which is going to contain a lot of very high quality images. To go with it the same application will be available as a chrome desktop app. I plan on using webview to point to an online version of the application without the images and to include these images with the app.

Can this be done? I can't seem to find an answer to this and know from android this can be done with webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.jpg"); but can't seem to get something similar working with a chrome app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to declare your local resources as accessible to your webviews. See https://codereview.chromium.org/22793018/patch/137001/138012 for a relevant example. I'm not able to find official documentation on this manifest key on my phone; please update this answer if you can.